# Добавление слов в массив

Tags: c, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы

Появилась задачка, в которой нужно через `scanf`, указать сначала число (сколько будет написано далее слов), а потом через <kbd>Enter</kbd>, написать те слова. Задача в том, что мне эти слова надо собрать в массив, но я понятия не имею как это можно сделать. Перепробовал кучу разных методов используя ввод слов через тип `scanf("%s")`, через `scanf("%c")`, пытался использовать `gets()`, но к сожелению желаемого результата недобился. Был бы очень благодарен, если бы кто-то объяснил как можно это сделать. Всем откликнувшимся заранее спасибо!

Comment: а где массив? Слов много?

Comment: `malloc()` -- выделяете память под указатели на все будущие слова массива, `scanf("%s", ...)` -- вводите очередное слово,`strdup()` -- запоминаете его копию в массиве ([man 3 ...](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html)  -- изучаете каждую из этих функций)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подход в выполнении задачи следующий. Мы задаем максимальную длину слова макросом `MAX_WORD_LENGTH`. Считываем с помощью функции [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) количество слов и записываем это значение в переменную `words_count`. Затем создаем *[массив переменного размера](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)* (*VLA*), который будет хранить массивы длины `MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1`. В каждый элемент этого массива записываем очередное слово с помощью функции `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_VALUE(x) STRING(x)
#define STRING(x) #x

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 120

int main(void)
{
    /* Считываем количество слов: */
    size_t words_count = 0;
    scanf("%zu", &words_count);

    /* Создаем variable length array (VLA), который будет
       хранить наши слова: */
    char words[words_count][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];

    /* Считываем слова функцией scanf:  */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words_count; ++i)
        scanf("%" STRING_VALUE(MAX_WORD_LENGTH) "s", words[i]);

    /* Печатаем все слова для проверки: */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words_count; ++i)
        printf("\n%zu: '%s'", i, words[i]);
}

#undef STRING_VALUE
#undef STRING
#undef MAX_WORD_LENGTH
```

Из-за применения VLA такой код точно будет работать только в C99. В стандарте C11 массивы переменного размера стали опциональными и проверить их поддержку вашей реализацией можно с помощью макроса `__STDC_NO_VLA__`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Хотя, конечно, можно отказаться от использования VLA можно и выделять память для слов динамически:</sup>

```
char (*words)[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1] = malloc(sizeof(*words) * words_count);
```

Comment: Возможно в качестве максимального размера слова лучше взять `LINE_MAX` из файла [limits.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/limits.h.0p.html) / А выделять память в стеке под все слова по максимуму несколько опрометчиво

Comment: @avp, `LINE_MAX` же нестандартный :) Ну, выделить память под все слова сразу проще всего, я старался писать как можно более проще. К тому же, VLA может и не на стеке хранится.

Comment: Нестандартный для кого? Давайте все же посмотрим правде в глаза и будем считать Linux стандартом (наверняка сейчас он работает в **миллиардах** девайсов). И с каких пор VLA выделяет память где-то кроме стека?

Comment: @avp, нестандартный для языка C. Почему бы не сделать код переносимым, если есть возможность? Никто не требует, чтобы память под VLA выделялась не стеке (хотя, конечно, вряд ли это можно где-нибудь увидеть вживую). И, конечно, вы правы, что такое «вольготное» использование памяти небезопасно.

Comment: Интернет утверждает, что `LINE_MAX`  *"compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 ("POSIX.1") specification"* (ну, и следующими POSIX тоже). В [библиотеке libc от GNU](http://www.sosst.sk/doc/glibc-doc/html/libc_31.html) он давным-давно есть. (В bsd unix он был еще в 80-е)

Comment: @avp, ну так то POSIX, а это ISO/IEC 9899:xxxx.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103777/discussion-between-avp-and-eanmos).